# Adding one more domain to my Hostgator server

Tags: .htaccess, dns

My client has bought two domains for his website: goiasverdade.com.br and goiasverdade.com

The main domain is goiasverdade.com.br, but he wants to redirect the visitors who enter the .com domain to the .com.br.

The .com.br domain is already registered in the Hostgator server. But now I don't know how to add another domain to the server and also redirect it to the main .com.br address. I have the DNS address for the .com domain, but where do I add it in the server Control Panel?.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to add the extra domain name as an [add on](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/please-read-before-creating-an-addon-domainadd-on) domain. Then I think you'd want to [redirect](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/url-redirect-how-to-create) the domain so that it redirects (forwards) to the other one.

Then you'll of course want to test everything to make sure everything works. If you're a developer, you may want to look at Digital Ocean or Linode hosting if you want to have more control over your servers.